# ValueError: too many values to unpack (sin/cos graph with Python 2.7)

Tags: python, animation, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot sin and cos on the same graph using Spyder (Python 2.7). I am able to plot a waving sin curve with this code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x,y)     
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
```

Now I tried to add a cos curve along with the sin curve and I modified the code by adding in a new variable (z) below the animation function to plot the cos curve. This is what I changed:

```
z = np.cos(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
line.set_data(x,y,x,z)
```

This is the new code altogether:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    z = np.cos(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x,y,x,z)     
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
```

However, I received:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1290, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 925, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 784, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 803, in _draw_next_frame
    self._draw_frame(framedata)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1106, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "C:/Users/Keegan/.xy/startups/sinwavegraph.py", line 28, in animate
    line.set_data(x,y,x,z)     
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 561, in set_data
    x, y = args
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any suggestions/recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot `set_data` to a line with four arguments. You need another line. See solution below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line1, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
line2, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line1.set_data([], [])
    line2.set_data([], [])
    return [line1, line2]

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    z = np.cos(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line1.set_data(x, y)
    line2.set_data(x, z)
    return [line1, line2]

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
plt.show()
```